# How do I begin to learn how to build a device like beaglebone or raspberry pi?

Tags: soc

I just want to learn how to get all the necessary components like intel cpu, amd or allwinner and wire them together.

How do I even start?

What knowledge I have.

1. CompSci Degree (Maths are covered here)

1a. Yes, still far away from EE degree but I think not so far.

2. Basic Arduino

2a. Very very basic microcontroller knowledge.

To clarify:
I just want to be able to buy ready made chips and put them together. Sort of like buying an Arduino, a smoke sensor and led. Make the led turn on if smoke sensor detects something

So to add on, can I buy a Mediatek Soc, some broadcom wifi chip, realtek ethernet and maybe some usb host controller and start piecing them together and install android or linux on it?

Comment: Go to college and get an EE degree, then get several years of relevant experience in the field.

Comment: In the meantime, learn as much math as possible.

Comment: You can start small with microcontrollers and breakout boards and jumper wires and get by.  But the things you are asking about have a lot of "analog" knowledge required to get the "digital" signals working.  Just powering the device and getting it out of reset, takes a fair amount of knowledge and experience.   DRAM alone is something the average engineer struggles with the first few (dozen) times, with their degree and years of experience.

Comment: @Daniel With an emphasis on "**years of relevant experience in the field**". Much of the knowledge necessary to design a device like that is not the stuff they teach you in school: DFM, passing regulatory hurdles, high-speed digital board design, etc.

Comment: @daniel, I probably don't have time for that. Getting an EE degree. I take that you're NOT dissuading me from learning.

Comment: I have to disagree with everyone here. I have the capabilities to lay out a Beaglebone/RPi type board, but my grades in EE were bad enough that I might as well not have attended. And I feel most of the valuable knowledge I gained during that time was through hands-on work, largely self-directed but with access to experienced people's advice. Conventional academics is not necessary.

Comment: Well, I have 10 years of relevant experience AND a degree. The degree just helps you understand and interpret what you encounter in the real world. Even with all that education and experience, what you're asking about is a very involved project that would take a single person months just to get the hardware right, depending on the feature set. I suggest you hire someone or forget about it and pick something simpler to start with.

Comment: I'm not dissuading you from learning, but it is frustrating to be confronted by this kind of naivety from technical people about the depth of other engineering fields and the knowledge and experience required to do many of the things we do.

Comment: I have the degree.  I think the experience is the bigger half of that statement from Daniel.  I have seen many folks without degrees do well, and even more with not so much.  The education however learned is necessary when the thing doesnt "just work" when you turn it on.  Digital design is nothing more than: zero; one; and; or; not.  Until there is a problem that becomes analog...Math is nothing more than counting, everything from addition to calculus are just shortcuts.  Those shortcuts are needed to get something done in a resonable amount of time.

Comment: When you get into hundreds of MHz and GHz and in this case laying out or even having someone layout dram and other high speed interfaces, you need the experience from somewhere.  for the most part it is simple stuff, address bit 0 wires to address bit 0 and so on.   Power is mostly just wiring it up like the reference design, but still there is experience required in the layout and if it doesnt "just work".  A microcontroller or other slow speed thing, you can just wire it up using pipe cleaners if you want and it will often just work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question is worded very innocently, but it asks for a *lot*:

- which components you should use
- how to connect them
- how to realize those connections on a PCB

You didn't specifically ask, but I asumme you also need to

- construct (solder) your product
- port some Linux version to run on in

Each of these steps will take an experienced person (who has done it a few times before) a considerable time, and probably a few iterations for bugfixing. Read up on the design history of the first Pi to get some idea.

Overall, you are looking at let's say 10 man-years of academic education (electronics and informatics, and both to a serious level), followed by 1 man-year of work.

You talk about 'wiring it together', but for the type of circuits you ask for that is not possible in the literal sense: the speed of the signal and the phyiscal size of the connections make it impossible to do this with separate wires. You need a PCB.

if you just want to know which components are used and how they are wired (as opposed designing and building your own version): there are lots of free designs available, check for instance the Olimex website.

Comment: [This is an interesting article.](http://www.wired.com/2012/09/raspberry-pi-insider-exclusive-sellout-to-sell-out/) It took 7 years to get raspberry Pi out and that too for an experienced team.

Comment: @wouter, i think I will start with which components are used and they are wired together first. Followed by designing my own. I have been interesting in these areas. I am picking up every aspects needed to do this. Slowly but surely.

Comment: As I said, you can check out the available open desifgns, and get their BOM and circuit diagrams.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I **begin to learn** how to build a device like beaglebone or
>   raspberry pi [emphasis mine]

As suggested in comments and other answers, building a fully complete turn-key device like this is a very tall order. This is why many people buy turn-key solutions: the heavy lifting has been done for you, and you can concentrate on your solution.

However, if we concentrate on the "beginning to learn" aspect to your question, there is a clear answer.

Just get started. Get a BBB or RaspPi or ODROID and start tinkering. Set aside time for *serious* hacking. Install a new OS to it. Flash an LED. Get it networking in interesting ways with other systems. Read forums and wikis dedicated to system internals. Build a simple circuit and interface it.

None of this will necessarily allow you to ever make your own turn-key system, but it will go a long way to showing you what is involved. Right now you don't even know what you don't know, so just have fun filling in those details.

Comment: The get started part. What I have done :
1. Own BBB and RaspPi
2. Installed  new OS.
3. Flash an LED like turn on and off. Done that using arduino

Forums and Wikis dedicated to system internal. Where do I start?

Comment: For where do i start. I mean if you can recommend some wikis and forums?

Comment: @henry - here's a good place to start! http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/ten-links-to-online-arduino-learning-resources.html

Comment: @henry, all projects start with an itch you want to scratch. Find an itch.